# How to make the logs to an ouput file in java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, logging

I manage the logs of my maven project with Logger **org.apache.log4j.Logger**

This is an example:

```
public transient Logger log = CommonLogger.getLogger(this.getClass());


log.info("start of : " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " : " + methodName);
```

So as you khnow the code above helps to show the log in the consol of eclipse but i want to export that logs shown on the consol dynamically to a file  in a personalized location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a log4j.properties file in the project classpath.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logs\\impalalog.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p 
%c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Thx @Pramod Karandikar